# what is "org.tensorflow.demo.R" mean in tensorflow's object detection app demo?

Tags: android, tensorflow, object-detection-api

I am trying to plant my tensorflow model on my phone recently, and I follow tensorflow's [guidence](https://www.tensorflow.org/mobile/android_build). In java file "CameraConnectionFragment.java", there is

> import org.tensorflow.demo.R; // Explicit import needed for internal Google builds.

I can not find what the R is on website. Anyone who knows about this?

Answer (score 0):

Tensorflow is a hidden Api  for camera sensor.

You can find the required jar in the following repository.

https://github.com/anggrayudi/android-hidden-api